# In Rust, is it possible to have a mutable copy-able string allocated on the stack?

Tags: rust

I need something that will make this work:

```
#[derive(Copy)]
struct TestData {
    val : MutableString
}
```

Presumably, the `MutableString` will have to be of fixed size, and I am okay with that.

Comment: If not using special crates, then you'll probably have to make a `[u8, N]` array, which you'll be manually interpreting as Unicode string

Comment: You could always create a byte array and then get a reference to it like `let mutable_string: &mut str = std::str::from_utf8_mut(&mut bytes).unwrap()`

Comment: The [`arrayvec` crate](https://crates.io/crates/arrayvec) has an [`ArrayString`](https://docs.rs/arrayvec/0.7.2/arrayvec/struct.ArrayString.html) that would work here.

Comment: You might have luck with the [bstr (byte string) crate](https://docs.rs/bstr/latest/bstr/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use const generics for this!

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct TestData<const SIZE1: usize> {
    val : MutableString<SIZE1>
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct MutableString<const SIZE: usize> {
    inner : [u8; SIZE],
    len: usize
}
```

(note: these are both `Copy`, but `Clone` must also be present due to trait bounds)

The `SIZE` parameter must be a value that is computable at compile time so you are right about needing fixed length strings.

We need a `len` field here because we need to know how long the actual string itself is. The alternative would be using a null-terminator like  C does.

I defined a couple methods to make one of these from an &str and turn one back into a &str:

```
impl<'a, const SIZE: usize> MutableString<SIZE> {
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        let slice = s.as_bytes();
        if slice.len() > SIZE {
            Err("String is too big")
        } else {
            let mut inner = [0; SIZE];
            for (i, byte) in slice.iter().enumerate() { inner[i] = *byte; }
            Ok(Self {
                inner,
                len: slice.len()
            })
        }
    }

    fn to_str(&'a self) -> &'a str {
        std::str::from_utf8(&self.inner).unwrap()
    }
}
```

In the real world you'd want more error handling around this and also offer methods that guard mutation to ensure it doesn't expand beyond `SIZE` or require `len` to be updated.

We can verify that the string is being copied:

```
fn main() {
    let mut_str = MutableString::from_str("Hello, world!").unwrap();
    let mut data: TestData<256> = TestData { val: mut_str };
    let copy = data;

    data.val.inner[12] = b'?'; // irl guard this around a method that updates len, etc.

    println!("{}", data.val.to_str());
    println!("{}", copy.val.to_str());
}
```

Comment: You could also use `data.val.inner[12] = b'?';`

Comment: Good point, thanks